# Will this be freed by Java Garbage Collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

If I have a class:

```
class node {
    int i; 
    node other;
}
```

Then I do the following steps in my program.

```
n1 = new node();
n2 = new node();
n1.other = n2;
n2.other = n1;
n1 = null;
n2 = null;
```

Will the memory occupied by n1 and n1 be freed by Java Garbage Collection?

Comment: Why do you think it would? Why do you think it wouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is assuming a reference-counting garbage collection implementation. Java instead uses mark-and-sweep. Mark-and-sweep starts at various known root objects (thread instances, the System object, etc) and traverses the object graph. Each object visited is marked as such. After the traversal, the unmarked (dead) objects are collected.

In your example, though the nodes reference each other, they cannot be reached from any live portion of the program, and will be freed.

Answer (score 0):

As a first approximation, an object is not garbage as long as there are references around. In your code you null'ed `n1` and `n2`, but there's the `other` field inside `node` class that still references those two objects.

If there are no more references to those objects in any collection, in any instance or static field, in any wrapper type, the JVM detects the cycle and marks the objects as garbage